# When are events handled when already executing?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

To set the stage, I have a custom class called `Scheduler` that holds multiple `Task` objects (this is a custom class as well). Each task has a `BackgroundWorker` object to run long running work. I am currently doing some testing of having many of these tasks executing quickly and being handled at the same time.

In my `Task` object, I raise an a custom event (`TaskCompletedEvent`) in the `TaskWorkerCompleted` handler to alert the scheduler that a task is completed. The scheduler uses the same event handler for every task's `TaskCompletedEvent`.

What I want to know is if I am currently in the `Scheduler` `TaskCompletedEvent` handler executing code and another event finishes up, what happens? Both are going to be on the UI Thread, so does the one currently in the event handler finish up before the other one proceeds? I'm getting confused on what is going to happen when two events finish simultaneously and need to be handled.

Comment: What do you mean, both are on the UI thread? If they are on the UI thread, they can't finish at the same time. Maybe a sample of your code could help.

Comment: How exactly do you raise the `TaskCompletedEvent`? Do you do that from the UI thread?

Comment: @svick Yes, I rase it from the UI Thread. I think Vlad answered my question. I just need to test out some code to make sure I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the events themselves don't know about the UI threads. So the events will be dispatched in the same thread where they are fired (this is most probably in the backgroundworker's thread, right?)

If your both events are fired in the UI thread, this cannot be simultaneous (after all, the UI thread is executing either one or another event firing code), so the second event isd perhaps going to be fired when the first event is finished with firing and dispatching.

If you want the `Scheduler` to marshal the events to the UI thread, that is a slightly different story. Your code which needs to be executed at the UI thread will be actually posted into a kind of event queue of that thread, and whatever event-firing code happens to be first, gets executed first.

Comment: The backgroundworker event is fired on the UI thread. I'm guess it uses Invoke. So I don't need to worry about those two events in being in the same method at the same time since they are on the same thread, correct?

Comment: @Justin: yes. The code in the UI thread will execute sequentially; when the first event is fired and all the event handlers finish, only than the UI thread looks for the next dispatched command, not simultaneously.